# Run Automation UI Testing through Selenium and Coded UI Without Build from TFS

Tags: selenium, tfs, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

Our web application codes are stored on SVN instead with TFS. We are trying to set up our automated UI testing.

These are following tools our team are considered to use.
 - Microsoft Test Manager (Create Test cases associate with User stories)
 - Coded UI (Connect to TFS and Microsoft Test Manager)
 - Selenium (Automated UI coded)
 - Team Foundation Server 2015 (Test cases and User stories)

Web Application with URL

We only want to configure automated UI testing for our website. Is there any way to run the set up the automated testing without build through TFS?

Thank you and any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the thing,

1. Coded Ui is not a connector to TFS & MTM it by itself an automation
   framework/tool like selenium
2. You don't need both Selenium & Coded UI for your automation. You only need either of it

If all you want is to get started with automation for your application, you can do it just with a version of visual studio which has Coded Ui. (The latest supporting version is [Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/enterprise/))

See this like to know [How to create Coded Ui Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#VerifyingCodeUsingCUITCreate) , see this link to know how to [Run a Coded Ui Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's based on your workflow. Whether your app/code is on-premises or in the cloud, you can automate **build-deploy-test** workflows and choose the technologies and frameworks, then test your changes **continuously** in a fast, scalable, and efficient manner. And just as *Prageeth* said,  Coded Ui is an automation framework/tool just like selenium.

In TFS either code ui or selenium test more like continuous testing. The workflow is such as bleow:

> First make sure that your app still works after every check-in and
>   build using TFS. **Find problems earlier by running tests
>   automatically with each build.** When your build is done, review your
>   test results to start resolving the problems that you find.

Add some related tutorials for your reference:

- How to run Code UI in TFS:  [Executing Automated tests in Build vNext
  using Test Plan, Test Suites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/)
- How to run Selenium  in TFS: [Get started with Selenium testing in a
  continuous integration pipeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium)

If you insist on without building from TFS, you could also use the Code UI function with VS on local.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Test controller and Test Agent VMs in MTM test lab. This will allow you to execute your automated tests on Test Agent directly in MTM. Otherwise, you can execute Coded UI tests locally in Visual Studio.